# Woocommerce few categories showing less products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing an issue regarding Woo-commerce category page products.
What is happening right now I added 1 new category and assign it to 10 products.
But when I am going to that page from user view it's showing me only 8 products.

And when I am clicking on the any filter of woo-commerce it's showing me 10 products.

It is happening in another category as well. On the page load it's showing 12 products and touching any filter it's showing me 16.

Why is this happening? could any one help me out?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could provide your code?

Comment: Actually i did not developed the site. And the site is using the theme electro.
Which code should I provide?